# Ubuntu 16.04 on Mac Power Book: no sound while running jackd without any errors (not your typical issue with jack audio)

Tags: sound, alsa

I know there are tons of posts about issues with jackaudio, but this one is not one of those, since jackd is running fine, and shows no issues or errors while running with the -v (verbose option) in a terminal.

Observations:

1. Alsamixer shows all outputs are on max
2. Sound without being routed thru jack does work:

   ```
   speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:PC
   ```
3. No error running jackd, connecting output to system and pumping stream from a jackd client (ecasound) :

   The following (as a simple way to test jack audio) run 
   without any errors:

   ```
   jackd -v -d alsa -r 44100 -P hw:PCH -C hw:PCH
   ecasound -f:32,1,44100 -i 1-long.mp3 -b:1024 -o:jack,system
   ```

Problem: I hear no sound from laptop's speakers! Inspecting connection or message thru qjackctl shows no issues (ie, connections are valid, and messages add no additional insight into what might be the problem).

For reference, the above simple commands successfully produce sound on a Sony VAIO.

Question: any suggestion how I can debug this? My hunch is that the sound devices are not correctly recognized either by alsa or jackd, but please not that pulseaudio works (a non jackd scenario).

Much appreciate any pointers, suggestions, etc. Thanks!

Attachments: txt result of runing alsa-info_alsa-info.sh from the alsa web site.[enter link description here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=5fa5bf36a339e4bd499a244a13f2d39bb7c31879)

Setup:

```
Manufacturer:      Apple Inc.
Product Name:      MacBookPro11,2
Product Version:   1.0
Firmware Version:  MBP112.88Z.0138.B02.1310181745

OS: ubunntu 16.04.1 desktop (running from live CD/USB). 
FYI, problem also reproduces on a clean install of Mint18
```

Comment: Correction to a typo, the speaker test command above should state : speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:PCH