# Ubuntu 16.04 on MacBook Pro: no sound with jackd, although ALSA is working

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, macbook, jack

This is likely to be a MacBook specific question, as I do not face this problem on other notebooks (Dell). The case is the following:

- ALSA sound is working fine. mplayer plays mp3 test files with sound over the speakers.
- `jackd` starts without errors
- Playing the same file with `mplayer -ao jack test.mp3` produces no error. jackd happily connects the mplayer outputs to the system playback. mplayer also runs without error.
- There is no sound.

There is another [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815213/ubuntu-16-04-on-mac-power-book-no-sound-while-running-jackd-without-any-errors) for the same subject, unfortunately without answer. The title says "Mac Power Book", but it's actually about the very same `MacBookPro11,2` that I use as well. The technical details there also apply to my case.

*Edit:* Here is a log I get from `qjackctl`, showing the sequence from starting to stopping jackd, with a connection from mplayer in the meantime. It does not complain when playing audio, but at the very beginning after the German message, there are 5 lines with strange content. They read like errors, but then it seems to start over and doesn't complain.

```
23:24:58.948 D-BUS: JACK-Server startet...
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
23:24:58.959 D-BUS: JACK-Server wurde gestartet (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: Starting jack server...
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: Acquired audio card Audio1
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: creating alsa driver ... hw:PCH|hw:PCH|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|hwmeter|-|32bit
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: configuring for 44100Hz, period = 1024 frames (23.2 ms), buffer = 2 periods
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_1'
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: New client 'system' with PID 0
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_2'
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_1'
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:monitor_1'
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_2'
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:monitor_2'
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_3'
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:monitor_3'
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_4'
Mon Aug 14 23:24:58 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:monitor_4'
23:25:01.091 JACK-Verbindung geändert.
23:25:01.092 Serverkonfiguration nach "/home/test1/.jackdrc" gespeichert.
23:25:01.092 Statistik zurückgesetzt.
23:25:01.108 Client aktiviert
23:25:01.109 Steckfeld deaktiviert.
23:25:01.142 Schaubild der JACK-Verbindungen geändert.
Mon Aug 14 23:25:00 2017: Saving settings to "/home/test1/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Mon Aug 14 23:25:01 2017: New client 'qjackctl' with PID 20955
23:25:05.891 Schaubild der JACK-Verbindungen geändert.
23:25:05.946 JACK-Verbindung geändert.
Mon Aug 14 23:25:05 2017: New client 'MPlayer [21081]' with PID 21081
Mon Aug 14 23:25:05 2017: Connecting 'MPlayer [21081]:out_0' to 'system:playback_1'
Mon Aug 14 23:25:05 2017: Connecting 'MPlayer [21081]:out_1' to 'system:playback_2'
23:25:09.557 Schaubild der JACK-Verbindungen geändert.
23:25:09.756 JACK-Verbindung geändert.
Mon Aug 14 23:25:09 2017: Disconnecting 'MPlayer [21081]:out_0' from 'system:playback_1'
Mon Aug 14 23:25:09 2017: Disconnecting 'MPlayer [21081]:out_1' from 'system:playback_2'
Mon Aug 14 23:25:09 2017: Client 'MPlayer [21081]' with PID 21081 is out
23:25:13.422 Client deaktiviert.
23:25:13.497 D-BUS: JACK-Server fährt herunter...
Mon Aug 14 23:25:13 2017: Client 'qjackctl' with PID 20955 is out
23:25:13.502 D-BUS: JACK-Server wurde angehalten (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Mon Aug 14 23:25:13 2017: Stopping jack server...
Mon Aug 14 23:25:13 2017: Client 'system' with PID 0 is out
Mon Aug 14 23:25:13 2017: Released audio card Audio1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run **alsamixer** in a terminal and check that there is no muted channel when jackd runs. 
Press F6 to check each  soundcard in case there more that one .

Also try to kill **pulseaudio** before running  jackd  , not so easy because pulseaudio is auto relaunched, so run these commands:
`mkdir .pulse`
`echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf`
`pulseaudio -k`
  Now pulseaudio is stopped, launch jackd.
(later, to revert to normal mode, run `echo autospawn=yes > ~/.pulse/client.conf` then `pulseaudio` )

Comment: Thanks, but it still isn't working. I checked alsamixer as well, and all is unmuted. I edited my question to add a log from qjackctl.

Comment: BTW: I have upvoted, but I am too junior for my vote to be displayed.

Comment: You could try to tweak parameters in Qjackctl:  audio interface in "parameters"  (if more than one). More settings in"advanced" : "output devices", ports, 16bits ...

Comment: Oh, I thought I had already tested any combination. But finally that did the trick. The I/O channels were set to default. I have set them to 2 now, and it works. Thanks a lot!